# HikariCp connection pool cannot reuse session after call to stored procedure in oracle database

Tags: java, spring, oracle, stored-procedures, hikaricp

I'm using

- spring boot 1.5.13
- spring 4.3.17
- database: oracle 12c 12.01.02
- connection pool: hikaricp 3.3.1

When I call the stored procedure it creates a session for every call instead of reusing the idle session.

I tried to change the call to the stored procedure 
in the following ways:

- @PersistenceContext entitymanger
- @autowire entityfactorymangeror
- @PersistenceUnite entityfactorymanger

but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

i found two solutions for this problem :

replace entitymenager.createstoredprocedure() with jpa annotation @procedure.
  The second option is add @transactional  add when we finish 
 use entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).disconnect;